# Using only patches to display a letter in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I am new to Netlogo and I wish to understand how to set the patches to show a static letter.

Is it possible for the patches to show a letter (e.g. letter D) without the use of turtles? I was thinking that patches could only have one color, so I am lost when it comes for the patches to display a letter? Is is possible to display a letter by changing the color of some coordinates? Even so, how should I retrieve the correct coordinates to actually be able to draw a real letter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that patches must all be one colour - they are squares of environment. So you can either do a very large letter by making it from small squares. Or (more easily) you can use the `plabel` variable that is owned by each patch. That variable can hold any value like a letter or a word - it is intended as a label for the patch.

If you have the default settings, then the centre patch is `patch 0 0`. That is both the name of the patch and the co-ordinates. And `patch 1 0` is the patch that is one to the right (x direction) of the centre. As well as the label, the variables automatically owned by a patch include the colour (as `pcolor`), x co-ordinate (`pxcor`) and y co-ordinate (`py-cor`).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation. But how could I construct the edges of the letter? For example I can see the simplicity of this for letter like E, but I have to construct a D which has oval edges... and patches are squared? I am a complete n00b so thanks for your help!

Comment: It sounds like you are wanting to use multiple patches for each letter. Use the settings to change the world size - have a very large number of small patches.